# iOS Charts 3.1.1 - X axis date values are not accurate and data is not plotted correctly

Tags: ios, json, swift, frameworks, ios-charts

So I'm working with a 3rd party framework called 'Charts' to handle displaying weight data in my app. But it looks weird, here's a photo of how it looks and then my code after it.

[image: my weight chart]

Some of the values are correct but only 2 of my 4 weight values are being displayed, furthermore the date below are increasing in increments of 6 months, I don't know why because I never specified this in my code, they aren't matching up with my weight values. Here is my weight objects I want to display.

```
"progressWeights": [
        {
            "weight": "200",
            "_id": "5af4c835b83893a9754b82ec",
            "createdOn": "2010-05-10T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "weight": "145",
            "_id": "5afe6614cbd4ff00323461ed",
            "createdOn": "2018-05-17T07:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "weight": "153",
            "_id": "5b0cbc8db62b190844cce1e9",
            "createdOn": "2010-05-28T00:00:00.000Z"
        },
        {
            "weight": "185",
            "_id": "5b0cbcadb62b190844cce1ea",
            "createdOn": "2018-05-25T00:00:00.000Z"
        }
]
```

Now here is some of my Weight Chart code:

```
// Chart Data
var weightData = [String]() 
var weightUploadDates = [String]()

func lineChartSetup() {

    // convertToDate and millisecondsSince1970 are helper methods, output is time interval
    let uploadDates = weightUploadDates.map({ convertToDate(str: $0).millisecondsSince1970 })

    // Line chart population
    setLineChart(dataPoints: weightData, values: uploadDates) 
}

func setLineChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Int]) {

    /*
     Here are what params are holding currently
     dataPoints:
      ▿ 4 elements
       - "200"
       - "145"
       - "153"
       - "185"

     values:
     ▿ 4 elements
       - 1273449600000
       - 1526540400000
       - 1275004800000
       - 1527206400000
    */

    var idx = 0
    // data point setup and color config
    for i in dataPoints {
        let dataPoint = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(values[idx]), y: Double(i)!) 
        dataEntry.append(dataPoint)
        idx += 1
    }

    // Setting up the data set for chart
    let chartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntry, label: "Weight")
    let chartData = LineChartData()
    chartData.addDataSet(chartDataSet)

    // Axes Setup
    let formatter: ChartFormatter = ChartFormatter()
    let str = values.map({ String($0) })
    formatter.setValues(values: str)
    let xaxis: XAxis = XAxis()
    xaxis.valueFormatter = formatter
    lineChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom
    lineChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    lineChartView.xAxis.valueFormatter = xaxis.valueFormatter // I think this might be the problem?

    lineChartView.data = chartData
}
```

I believe the source of the problem is the x axis value formatter, as you can see in the picture above the dates don't match any of the ones from my weight objects and they aren't aligned properly with my weight data. Here is my value formatter code:

```
public class ChartFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {

    var weightData = [String]()

    // This sets the x axis? - Dates go up by 6 months for some reason?...
    public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
        //print("String for value desc \(value)")
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM/dd"
        let date = dateFormatter.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
        return date
    }

    public func setValues(values: [String]) {
        self.weightData = values
    }
}
```

When my chart gets displayed the print statement in the 'stringForValue' method gets called almost a hundred times, here's some of the output:

```
String for vlaue desc 1280000000000.0
The date value: 08/02
String for vlaue desc 1320000000000.0
The date value: 02/18
String for vlaue desc 1360000000000.0
The date value: 09/07
String for vlaue desc 1400000000000.0
The date value: 03/27
String for vlaue desc 1440000000000.0
The date value: 10/13
String for vlaue desc 1480000000000.0
```

It seems like my first date value (1273449600000) is being rounded to 1280000000000.0 and then 40000000000 is being added for each iteration? I don't know where this is coming from and it shouldn't be doing this.

So that is my issue, any ideas on how to get the x axis to only hold the 4 date objects I have and to have it match it's appropriate weight value? Any help is appreciated. Let me know if there is more info that you need.

Comment: print date formater date its returning same or different ?

Comment: In the output above you can see the statement, 'The date value: ', this is what you're referring too right? Look at the values you see it starts at 8/02 then the next output is 2/18, then 9/07. It's increasing by 6 months or so. Also look at the time intervals above it, that supports my claim.